# Checking if the first and last element of a string is an alphanumerical character with patterns

Tags: php

I want to check if the first and last element of a string is an alphanumerical character and it doesn't matter how big the string is.
To check it I use a little script:

```
if(preg_match("/^\w\w$/", $_GET['eq'])){ 
    echo "<h1>true</h1>"; 
}else{ 
    echo "<h1>false</h1>"; 
}
```

But if the input contains more than 2 characters it says false. How can I check a bigger string? In my opinion `/^\w\w$/` should check the first and last character doesn't matter how big the string is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, it will accept anything but first and last character will be alphanumeric.

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}.*[A-Za-z0-9]{1}?$/i', $_GET['eq'])){ 
    echo "<h1>true</h1>"; 
}else{ 
    echo "<h1>false</h1>"; 
}
```

expression explanation :

```
^ Beginning. Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.
[ Character set. Match any character in the set.
A-Z Range. Matches a character in the range "A" to "Z" (char code 65 to 90).
a-z Range. Matches a character in the range "a" to "z" (char code 97 to 122).
0-9 Range. Matches a character in the range "0" to "9" (char code 48 to 57).
]
{1} Quantifier. Match 1 of the preceding token.
. Dot. Matches any character except line breaks.
* Star. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
[ Character set. Match any character in the set.
A-Z Range. Matches a character in the range "A" to "Z" (char code 65 to 90).
a-z Range. Matches a character in the range "a" to "z" (char code 97 to 122).
0-9 Range. Matches a character in the range "0" to "9" (char code 48 to 57).
]
{1} Quantifier. Match 1 of the preceding token.
? Lazy. Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
$ End. Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.
```

Answer (score 2):

You must match and ignore all the middle characters: `/^\w.*\w$/`

So, your code must be:

```
if(preg_match("/^\w.*\w$/", $_GET['eq'])){ 
    echo "<h1>true</h1>"; 
}else{ 
    echo "<h1>false</h1>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can use

```
^\w.*\w$
```

The `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if(preg_match("/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['eq'])){ 
    echo "<h1>true</h1>"; 
}else{ 
    echo "<h1>false</h1>"; 
}
```

You need to be able to skip all the characters in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp as it is will only match a 2-character string. Try this one instead (`.*` will allow it to optionnally expand in the middle):

```
if(preg_match("/^\w.*\w$/", $_GET['eq'])){ 
    echo "<h1>true</h1>"; 
}else{ 
    echo "<h1>false</h1>"; 
}
```